# Как скопировать один лист в другой. Google Таблицы

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-spreadsheet

создаю приложение на Node.js, выношу данные из одного сайта и заношу в гугл таблицы. Вроде бы всё понятно, но есть одно, в таблице есть лист с формой, и мне нужно как-то скопировать этот лист и внести в него уже данные. Конечно можно создать по новой лист со всеми цветами и шрифтами, но это будет прямой признак мазахиста. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно скопировать один лист и создать другой такой-же, при этом, как мне в будущем заносить данные. Буду очень благодарен ответам.